# Which of the following microcontrollers can talk to a CC3000 WiFi chip?

Tags: microcontroller, wifi

I need to build a hardware device that consists of a microcontroller and a CC3000 WiFi chip. I would like to use any one of the following microcontrollers built by Texas Instruments:

- MSP430F2491
- MSP430F249-EP
- MSP430F29
- MSP430F2370
- MSP430F2350
- MSP430F235

Which of the above MC's are suitable for communicating with the CC3000 WiFi chip?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of the above. The CC3000 boosterpack is even bundled with the Valueline MSP430 Launchpad, which comes with the MSP430G2553, which only has 16kb flash and 512 BYTE ram. All of the above have more ram, and some have less flash memory, but you can get the CC3000 working with just 2~6kb of flash. The CC3000 has all of the TCP-IP stack onboard, so very little is needed on the microcontroller side to get it working.